# How to assign id to an element through Selenium

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium

In Selenium you access the underlying DOM of the browser which you are manipulating through IWebElement instances. Like this:

```
IWebElement domWrapper = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
```

Lets say you have the "domWrapper" instance as shown in the example above, you do not however have the right side of the equation; which means that you a) don't know what the element actually represents and b) you don't know how it was located. Given these two pre-conditions is it possible to assign an id to the element using selenium? All the examples I've seen for assigning an id to the element leverages javascript and a locator to find the instance in the dom.

How I originally phrased the question (which no-one understood :-))

Any ideas as to how I can assign an id to an arbitrary element in Selenium? I have a reference through the IWebElement interface to the element in the DOM and I know that the driver supports execution of Javascript, I just don't know how to refer to an element uniquely when it has no id.

Psedu code example (this code locates the dom element to manipulate the id by ussing an attribute which it uniquely set, in my case I have no such unique attributes to lean on).

```
    public string Id
    {
        get { return GetAttribute("id"); }
        set
        {
            var finder = string.Format("document.querySelector('[{0}=\"{1}\"]')", "data-bind", element.GetAttribute("data-bind"));

            string setId = "('id', '_id__'+(Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000)+1));";
            string js = finder + ".setAttribute" + setId + ";";
            Driver.ExecuteJavascript(js);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Am I right that you just need to get this element and than click on it or something like that? If I'm right, html code will be very helpful. It is easier to get element by some locator, than assign an ID to the element.

Comment: I'm not trying to click it, I don't have the locator that led to the match, if so it would be easy as you say. I have the IWebElement instance in Selenium and basically thats it.

Comment: I can't believe there is no match by any locators. Have you tried xpath?

Comment: May be we have some misunderstanding? Your goal is to get Element or to set ID for already located element?

Comment: I can match any specific element given a locator, but this is generic code. I don't know how the element was located and since it does not have an id, I cant refer to it directly, hence my question.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?`Driver.ExecuteJavascript("arguments[0].setAttribute('id','123');", element);`

Comment: The real question is obtaining that element reference in the DOM if you only have the IWebElement dom-wrapper in Selenium

Comment: Can't understand what you want, sorry.

Comment: Because selenium has a getattribute method which you can use to check if the element has an id, but there is no corresponding setattribute method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of IWebElement in Selenium when accessing the DOM is actually a proxy for the 'real' DOM-element (equivalent of doing e.g. document.getElementsByClass, or similar). This in turn means that you can pass the IWebElement as an argument for a Javascript-method passed to the browser.

The easiest way to do this, is to pass a script to the browser that creates a new function taking in two arguments - the DOM-element and the new Id:

In Javascript the function would look like this:

```
var setId = function(elem, newId)
{
   elem.id = newId
};
```

and we'd call it like this:

```
setId(document.elementFromPoint(1, 2), 'myNewId');
```

So from Selenium, we can utilize the ExecuteJavascript method we get when casting the IWebDriver to IJavaScriptExecutor:

```
public void SetIdForElement(IWebElement element, string id)
{
     // same as above, compressed to a one-liner.
     string scriptString = "sId=function(e, i){e.id = i;};sId(arguments[0], arguments[1]);"

     ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(scriptString, element, id);
}
```

You can now easily set the ID for any element you have access to from your Selenium tests.